# Creating a class for a vector in 3 dimensions

Tags: python, class, vector, pytest

I want to create a class Vector3D for a three-dimensional vector in python. I want to be able to run the code through this test using pytest and have it "pass". I am very new to programming so im not really sure where to start. Do I just have to make the class using `__init__`? An example for using an array would be

```
class Vector3D:
      def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.data = np.array([x,y,z])
```

Could I just run this through test_vector3d.py (listed below) and granted that I've represented it "correctly" (like I haven't done in the example) it would pass the tests?

Or do I have to define the different attributes of the vector for it to pass the tests? As an example do I have to define addition within the class of `Vector3D` for it to know what to do when `test_addition` is called in `test_vector3d.py`?

Example:

```
 def addition(self, other):
        x1, y1, z1 = self.vec
        x2, y2, z2 = other.vec
        return VectorList(x1+x2, y1+y2, z1+z2)
```

Here is the test called `test_vector3d.py`. I want to be able to input:

```
pytest test_vector3d.py
```

into a command prompt and have my `Vector3D` class pass all the tests.

```
from vector3d import Vector3D

def test_constructor():
    v = Vector3D(1, 2, 3)
    assert type(v) == Vector3D
    assert v.x == 1
    assert v.y == 2
    assert v.z == 3

def test_addition():
    v1 = Vector3D(1,2,3)
    v2 = Vector3D(5,7,3)
    v3 = v1 + v2
    assert v3.x == 6
    assert v3.y == 9
    assert v3.z == 6

def test_subtraction():
    v1 = Vector3D(5,6,2)
    v2 = Vector3D(2,5,10)
    v3 = v1 - v2
    assert v3.x == 3
    assert v3.y == 1
    assert v3.z == -8

def test_multiplication():
    v1 = Vector3D(2,2,2)
    v2 = Vector3D(4,2,1)
    v3 = v1 * v2
    assert v3.x == 8
    assert v3.y == 4
    assert v3.z == 2

def test_equality():
    v1 = Vector3D(1,2,3)
    v2 = Vector3D(1,2,3)
    assert v1 == v2

def test_string():
    v1 = Vector3D(1,2,3)
    assert str(v1) == "[1,2,3]"

def test_repr():
    v1 = Vector3D(1,2,3)
    assert repr(v1) == "Vector3D(1,2,3)"

def test_length():
    v1 = Vector3D(10,0,0)
    assert v1.length() == 10
    v2 = Vector3D(2,2,2)
    # Tolerance used due to floating point
    assert v2.length() > 3.46 and v2.length() < 3.47

def test_dot():
    v1 = Vector3D(3,2,5)
    v2 = Vector3D(7,2,1)
    dot = v1.dot(v2)
    assert dot == 30

def test_cross():
    v1 = Vector3D(1,2,3)
    v2 = Vector3D(5,4,3)
    v3 = v1.cross(v2)
    assert v3.x == -6
    assert v3.y == 12
    assert v3.z == -6
```

Comment: Did you run the tests on your code? Where exactly does it fail? What do you have to change for it to pass?

Comment: This question seems like you're asking the StackOverflow community to do your homework for you. That's strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the following Python tutorials:

- [How to write a Python class.](https://medium.com/swlh/declare-your-first-python-class-understand-3-basic-components-15768c8d35b0)
- [Executing test runners in Python](https://realpython.com/python-testing/#executing-test-runners)

The TLDR of it is that you'll begin with a class definition like

```
class Vector3D(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

You'll need to define additional methods for adding vectors together, and doing any other operations or inspections.

I prefer the "unittest" package to the base testing framework you seem to be using, but that requires a bit of editing from what you've shown. If you're using pytest instead of unittest, that's fine - but it's still useful to understand a bit about what the test frameworks are doing in the background.

To run the test under unittest, you may need to edit it a bit from what you've shown, adding `import unittest` at the top and

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Invocation can then be done from the command line like `python -m unittest test`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30152303)

Comment: @Rizwan Fair. Part of my hesitation is I've been marked down before for answering questions that look too much like homework assignments. Trying to leave out some details so that I'm guiding OP in the right direction without doing the work for them.

Comment: Im sorry that it seems like im asking someone to do the work for me. I was just looking for a place to start, so being guided in the right direction is what i wanted. I just provided the rest of the assignment as context, since im not sure if i my questions would be understandable if i only tried explaining them.